# Selenium send HTML to stdout and errors to stderr

Tags: python, selenium

I have this script which works.. But I want to send the HTML to stdout and the errors (exceptions) to stderr

```
import time
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver

def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")

    try:
        box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, "q")))
        box.send_keys(query)
        button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.NAME, "btnG")))
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print "Box or Button not found in google.com"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver, "Selenium")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
    display.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess

```
except TimeoutException:
    print>>sys.stderr, "Box or Button not found in google.com"
```

but by default sys.stdout ,sys.stderr both print to the console I think